# what does jvm do to use multicore cpu resource?

Tags: java, multithreading, multicore

Usually a java program is running with a single process called "javaw".And when I run a single process I can only get max resource of one core(of multicores).
But when I run a multithread program in jvm, the number of cores it used is according to the number of threads which is beyond one process can do. So can anyone give me some information about how jvm deal with multithread program in multicore cpu machine ?

```
/**
* I run this program in my machine which has 8 core cpu
* and the jre is 1.6.0_24
* How does jvm use one process to use all the cpu resources?        
*/

public class MultiCoreUseTest implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {

    int i;
    while(true)
         i =1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create 8 threads
            //8 threads the usage of cpu is 100%
            // if 4 threads the usage of cpu is 50%
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
        new Thread(new MultiCoreUseTest()).start();     
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You do understand that a process can create one or more threads right?

Comment: yes, a process can hava multithreads. But in my understanding the jvm is a single process which manage the threads of java program, and a java thread is not eaquals to a thread in kernel, and I think this is the difference of 'p_thead' in c with 'Thread' in java. And may I wrong.

Comment: @newand Yes, you are wrong. A Java-thread is set up and executed as an OS-native thread (or child-process if on *nix) by the JVM.

Comment: The moral of the story; when it comes to performance you should only worry about issues you have measured to be a problem. IMHO, About half the questions on performance on SO are for things which were not a real problem in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The threads of one process can be distributed across different CPUs and CPU cores, just as individual processes can.  Just because an application has one process does not mean that its many threads are bound to one CPU/core.

Comment: so the method of OS deals with  theads which created by java program is the same with which created by C?

Comment: There are quite a few C libraries that implement threads.  My understanding is that some of them can take advantage of multiple CPUs/cores, and some cannot.  On most (if not all) desktop platforms, Java is able to take advantage of multiple CPUs/cores with its threading implementation.